# Can I swap round a built wall in Rust from soft side to hard side?

Tags: rust

I have made an error in my base, meaning that I have a single side of wooden wall piece with the soft side facing out.  What are my options for fixing this?

I can demolish it slowly with an axe and re place it the start way - or if I upgrade it to stone would the rotate piece option be enabled for a bit again on the hammer?  I don't want to run the risk of upgrading it to stone without being able to rotate it as that would be a real pain to demolish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade the wall to stone or metal and then rotate it, otherwise @kevinthegreat is correct, you will have to demolish the wall and replace it.

EDIT: When upgrading you can rotate a wall when you go from twig -> wood, wood -> stone, stone -> metal and metal -> armoured. Once the wall is fully upgraded or if you skip straight to armoured you cannot rotate it via upgrading.

Comment: if you skip to armored there is no rotation cause there is no reason to rotate. there is no soft side to armored. thus no rotation

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to demolish it, after placement there is a 10 minute window in which you can rotate the wall, [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/playrust/comments/4y1dk6/rotate_walls/).

Comment: Your quoted source says there is also a 10 minute window **after** upgrading too.